# what is the recommended way to use Clarity component in AngularJs (Angular 1.x) Application.

Tags: vmware-clarity

I am working in an application built on Angular 1.7, Now without migrating it to Angular 2.x, is there any way to use clarity components?

Comment: It may depend on what your needs and use case are. You might be able to use use ngUpgrade (https://angular.io/guide/upgrade) to integrate new Clarity components into your application.

Comment: If you don't want to upgrade, you can't use the angular components, but you could use the UX and the HTML examples wrapping it in your own Angular1 components. For example, https://vmware.github.io/clarity/documentation/v0.11/alerts shows HTML examples of how to get the Clarity L&F